# Add private assets to build in NextJS

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm using NextJS 12.
I want to be able to import some JSON and csv assets in my src folder. I would prefer to be able to do this using `readFileSync`, but when I run `next build` it doesn't bundle those assets into the production bundle. I know this because I've checked the bundle for mentions of those file names.

I'm not sure what to do. I could import JSON files with es6 syntax, but that's not convenient as there are a lot of different files and I would like to conditionally import one of them, not all of them at the beginning. But for csv files, I'm not sure what to do.

Also, I can't use the public folder, as these assets are meant to be private and not able to be shared with the client

Tldr: Need to add dynamically imported assets to production bundle in Next 12

Reproduction steps: Tried running `next build`. Expected to find those assets in the production bundle, but they weren't there, and wasn't able to load them in production.